# Number of integer solutions to $a_1\ge a_2\ge\ldots\ge a_i\gt 0$ such that $a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_i=n$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

What is the number of (positive) integer solutions of:

$$a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_i=n$$

where $a_1 \ge a_2 \ge \ldots\ge a_i\gt 0$ ?

Also, the order of summands does not matter.

Comment: any limits on $n$ ? and number of variables a,b,c ? Also please include what you tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for the number of **restricted partitions of $n$ into $i$ parts**.  This would be notated as $p_i(n)$.  [Read more about it here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29).  This happens to also equal the number of partitions of $n$ whose largest part is of size $i$, which is why the notation $p_i(n)$ does not distinguish between the two and just refers to it as a restricted partition of $n$.  Convenient recurrence relations and generating functions are shown on the site, but closed form expressions are rather ugly.

Comment: @E.Girgin: In editing the Question you changed the final strong inequality $a_i \gt 0$ to the weak inequality $a_i \ge 0$.  This has the effect of including partitions with fewer than $i$ parts in the counted number.  I'm going to change this back, assuming you made this inadvertently.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You may deal with the sub-case $a_1>a_2>\ldots>a_m>0$ and $\sum a_k = n$ first.

By setting $a_1-a_2=b_1, a_2-a_3= b_2, \ldots a_m=b_m$, we want to count the solutions of:
$$ b_1 + 2 b_2 +\ldots + m b_m = n $$
with $b_m\in\mathbb{N}^+$. That can be done through [a classical argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1804609/number-of-solutions-to-xyz-n).  Then account for the cases in which some of the inequalities $a_1\geq a_2\geq a_3\ldots\geq a_m$ hold as equalities.